# Elasticsearch multi_match + nested search

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to execute a multi_match + nested search in ElasticSearch 6.4. I have the following mappings:

```
      "name" : {
        "type" : "text"
      },
      "status" : {
        "type" : "short"
      },
      "user" : {
        "type" : "nested",
        "properties" : {
          "first_name" : {
            "type" : "text"
          },
          "last_name" : {
            "type" : "text"
          },
          "pk" : {
            "type" : "integer"
          },
          "profile" : {
            "type" : "nested",
            "properties" : {
              "location" : {
                "type" : "nested",
                "properties" : {
                  "name" : {
                    "type" : "text",
                    "analyzer" : "html_strip"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
```

And this is the html_strip analyzer:

```
        "html_strip" : {
          "filter" : [
            "lowercase",
            "stop",
            "snowball"
          ],
          "char_filter" : [
            "html_strip"
          ],
          "type" : "custom",
          "tokenizer" : "standard"
        }
```

And my current query is this one:

```
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": {
                "multi_match": {
                    "query": 'Paris',
                    "fields": ['name', 'user.profile.location.name']
                },
            },
            "filter": {
                "term": {
                    "status": 1
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Obviously searching for "Paris" in `user.profile.location.name` doesn't work. I was trying to adapt my code to following this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/48836012/12007123 but without any success.

What I am basically trying to achieve, is to be able to search for a value in multiple fields, this may or may not be nested.

I was also checking this discussion https://discuss.elastic.co/t/multi-match-query-string-with-nested-and-non-nested-fields/118652/5 but everything I tried wasn't successful.

If I just search for name, the search is working fine.

Any tips on how can I achieve this the right way, would be much appreciated.

**EDIT**:

While I didn't get an answer to my initial question, I was following Nikolay's (@nikolay-vasiliev) comment and changed th mappings to Object instead of Nested.

At least now I am able to search in `user.profile.location.name`. This is how the new mapping for user looks like:

```
      "user" : {
        "properties" : {
          "first_name" : {
            "type" : "text"
          },
          "last_name" : {
            "type" : "text"
          },
          "pk" : {
            "type" : "integer"
          },
          "profile" : {
            "properties" : {
              "location" : {
                "properties" : {
                  "name" : {
                    "type" : "text",
                    "analyzer" : "html_strip"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
```

Comment: I have not tried to run your query on my machine but I guess you have to do something like  "nested" : {
            "path" : "user", query:{ "nested": {path: profile}}, nested : { path: location ...

Comment: May I ask you why do you declare 4 levels of [`nested`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html)? Even single level of `nested` has poor performance, with 4 levels I expect it to be more than poor. May you show an example document? In general you don't have to declare sub-documents `nested`, generic [`object`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/object.html) type can do.

Comment: JBone: tried. Doesn't Work. 
@NikolayVasiliev I am using https://github.com/sabricot/django-elasticsearch-dsl and this how the mappings are added during indexing. I will try to create them using just the elasticsearch-dsl

Comment: @NikolayVasiliev Thanks. Following your suggestion, it works. I have updated the question, but the initial question still remains unanswered

Comment: Just to clarify, may you tell which is the part that still doesn't work? Searching `Paris` in many fields with `multi_match`?

Comment: @NikolayVasiliev it doesn't work with multi_match and type = nested. But it works with multi_match and object datatype as you suggested.